# Create score from various features/variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, embeddings

I have 4 measurements for different sensors and I would like to somehow create a score for each measurement ranging from 1-10. I have tried performing PCA with 1 component on these 4 columns and then rescaling the component to 1-10 but it's obvisously wrong. Any ideas? I'm using pandas in python.

Comment: Please add more details, if possible add an example of the data.